# Is it preferable to describe a computer's ephemeral visual data output device as a "monitor", "display", "screen", or something else?

Tags: terminology, guidelines, language, hardware, displays

In English language UIs, is it preferable to describe a computer's ephemeral data visual data output device as a "monitor", "display", "screen", or something else?

All three of those English words can be used as verbs and nouns, leading to a little potential confusion.

Is there a standard or commonly accepted recommendation?

Comment: Generally, I would say a "monitor" is actually the whole thing, where as a screen or display would be a *part* of the monitor. I think really it depends on what exactly you are trying to say and the context of where you are saying it. For example, a desktop PC would have a monitor, but a tablet device would not.

Comment: @musefan Good point. Ideally, it would be a single term that can be used across platforms (desktop computer, laptop, tablet, etc.).  What's interesting is that the term "monitor" seems to possibly be best for desktop computers, but isn't really used for tablets (as you pointed out).

Comment: Well, I think in the IT industry "Screen" would be universally understood for all cases, however if your target audience is less technical then that might not work.

Comment: I'd like to know more about the context - often referring specifically to the display output of a feature or information can limit its accessibility to, for example, users of screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

I think now the 'screen' is more platform independent term. Here is citation from [some web resource](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/o/outputsc.htm) which seemes to be relevant:

> An output **screen** is a device used *to display* output. An output **screen** could be a separate *monitor* or another *display* device used only *to display* the output being received from the computer or other devices.

Comment: In a head up display in a car, the screen is literally the windscreen.